# How to count columns from multiple rows

Tags: cassandra, hector

How can I count number of columns in different rows of a column family?

I am a Cassandra newbie. I do not know a starting point. The only option I have is to make the application fetch data for each row at a time. It does not sound right to me. I am using Hector to connect to Cassandra.

Answer (score 1):

this is how you will get total column count in particular rowkey

```
sliceQuery.setColumnFamily("**your column family**");
sliceQuery.setKey("**your row key**");
sliceQuery.setRange(null, null, false, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

QueryResult<ColumnSlice<String, String>> result = sliceQuery.execute();
ColumnSlice<String, String> cs = result.get();

long noOfColumnInRowKey=result.get().getColumns().size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have wide row (Lets create it using CLI)

```
create column family cf3 
 with column_type = 'Standard' and 
 comparator = 'TimeUUIDType' and 
 key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type' and 
 default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type';
```

This is what I see in CQL3:

```
cqlsh:ks> desc table cf3;

CREATE TABLE cf3 (
  key text,
  column1 timeuuid,
  value text,
  PRIMARY KEY (key, column1)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE AND
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};
```

I inserted some values from CQL3, which makes you feel like good ol' MySQL

```
cqlsh:ks> insert into cf3 (key, column1, value) values ('user1', now(), 'time5');
cqlsh:ks> select * from cf3;

 key   | column1                              | value
-------+--------------------------------------+-------
 user1 | f0c687b0-d114-11e2-8002-2f4261da0d90 | time1
 user1 | fb9fa130-d114-11e2-8002-2f4261da0d90 | time2
 user1 | 09512f10-d115-11e2-8002-2f4261da0d90 | time3
 user1 | 0f5c93e0-d115-11e2-8002-2f4261da0d90 | time4
 user1 | 21155220-d115-11e2-8002-2f4261da0d90 | time5
```

But it's your wide-row (as seen from CLI)

```
[default@ks] list cf3;
Using default limit of 100
Using default column limit of 100
-------------------
RowKey: user1
=> (column=f0c687b0-d114-11e2-8002-2f4261da0d90, value=time1, timestamp=1370789864363000)
=> (column=fb9fa130-d114-11e2-8002-2f4261da0d90, value=time2, timestamp=1370789882563000)
=> (column=09512f10-d115-11e2-8002-2f4261da0d90, value=time3, timestamp=1370789905537000)
=> (column=0f5c93e0-d115-11e2-8002-2f4261da0d90, value=time4, timestamp=1370789915678000)
=> (column=21155220-d115-11e2-8002-2f4261da0d90, value=time5, timestamp=1370789945410000)

1 Row Returned.
Elapsed time: 105 msec(s).
```

Now, you wanted to count number of columns starting from a given time onwards. Right? Here is CQL3 for that.

```
cqlsh:ks> select count(*) from cf3 where key = 'user1' and column1 >= 09512f10-d115-11e2-8002-2f4261da0d90 ;

 count
-------
     3
```

Now, I am somewhat doubtful what goes beneath. But, my intuition says that actually all the columns gets fetched at coordinator node and counted in memory. Which is probably somewhat similar to what you were planning to manually on client machine.

Also, I am unaware if cassandra-cli provides such functionality, but you mentioned you are using Hector. So, you can leverage `get_count` or [CountQuery](http://hector-client.github.io/hector/source/content/API/core/1.0-1/me/prettyprint/hector/api/query/CountQuery.html) like mentioned [here](https://github.com/rantav/hector/blob/master/core/src/test/java/me/prettyprint/hector/api/ApiV2SystemTest.java#L1062) except have `null` as range finish and large count value. Like this:

```
CountQuery<String, String> cq = HFactory.createCountQuery(keyspace, StringSerializer.get(), TimeUUIDSerializer.get());
cq.setColumnFamily(cf).setKey("user1");
cq.setRange(timestamp, null, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
QueryResult<Integer> r = cq.execute();
```

(uncompiled code above)

HTH

---

Old answer:

See Hector [documentation](http://hector-client.github.io/hector/build/html/content/cql_basics.html):

CQL:

```
CqlQuery<String,String,Long> cqlQuery = new CqlQuery<String,String,Long>(keyspace, se, se, le);
cqlQuery.setQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StandardLong1 WHERE KEY = 'cqlQueryTest_key1'");
QueryResult<CqlRows<String,String,Long>> result = cqlQuery.execute();
assertEquals(2, result.get().getAsCount());
```

You may just *miss* the `WHERE` condition and use `LIMIT` to get your purpose solved.

Comment: This works for a single row. what I need is to count columns starting from a given column name for each row with a single query. eg if row key is a username and column names are timestamps, given 100 usernames and 100 timestamps each corresponding to a username, how do I get count of columns for each row beginning at the given timestamp?

Comment: Do you want a count per row or a single count for all rows?

Comment: @Richard I wanted to do exactly what Nishant has done above but for multiple rows. Something like a 'multigetcountslicequery' if there was anything like that. But it doesn't matter now because I have found out that these count queries are slow so I opted to use a counter column which I reset  to start counting from a given time.